# The expected type comes from property 'src' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<SourceHTMLAttributes<HTMLSourceElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react with typescript. In my project, I am using forwardRef on my video tag, Here I am getting an error on a source tag of the video saying:

Type 'PropsWithChildren' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
Type 'PropsWithChildren' is not assignable to type 'string'

Here is my code:

```
type VideoType = {
    videoSource: string
}

const Player: ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLVideoElement, VideoType> = (videoSource, ref) => {
  return <video className='player' ref={ref}>
  <source src={videoSource} />
</video>;
};

export default forwardRef(Player);
```

Comment: Try using paranthesis around video html tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice job on the types! You just need to destructure `videoSource` in your props:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=13&ssc=23&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAGjjWgHcMolS0BfWqCEOAcijKVeAbgBQomAE8wKOADVgqCABVpsgLyJRcOADdFKCAGUIWKORQAuOARhRgAOwDmYtmNHkID23AAKODEkUKDhNOihGZlYAHgAJZQBZABkFJQBRHBQQFAdqeQMVNQA+AAoShH0lEzMLNhoBNABKUKK4Eu04aMrDOHIAggIAOQxs9QAiMACgqDHEADoFhAa2NiKOnWiCU3NZAnN1CoLqnY4AejWN0+6INcbG9xQAD0hYOFRMXHh-QOCxIA)

```ts
import {default as React, forwardRef} from 'react';

type VideoType = {
  videoSource: string;
};

const Player = forwardRef<HTMLVideoElement, VideoType>(({videoSource}, ref) => (
  <video className="player" {...{ref}}>
    <source src={videoSource} />
  </video>
));

export default Player;
```